# IONIC Notificação erro

Tags: angularjs, ionic, firebase, ionic3

Está ocorrendo esse erro na minha aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, poste o seu código em texto e não em imagem. Assim fica mais fácil para nós analisarmos e talvez utilizarmos o código nas nossas respostas.

Comment: E porque você colocou a tag [tag:firebase]? Não vejo nada relacionado com o firebase no seu código.